# What is Time format that is same everywhere?

Tags: datetime, internationalization

Suppose I'm creating a sweepstake, and I want to say it ends at 13:00 XXX.

Now for some people 13:00 would 1:00 am and for some it'd be 2:15 pm etc.

What is that format called from which everyone else derive their time if they want to. And it's universal, Same Value regardless of what time zone you are in.

UTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTC is the Coordinated Universal Time and is the same everywhere. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> Coordinated Universal Time (French: Temps universel coordonné),
>   abbreviated as UTC, is the primary time standard by which the world
>   regulates clocks and time. It is within about 1 second of mean solar
>   time at 0° longitude;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) it does not observe daylight saving time. It
>   is one of several closely related successors to Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT). For most purposes, UTC is considered interchangeable with GMT,
>   but GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community.

Comment: I've read that it didn't seem to directly answer my problem. So just to be clear, if at 3pm in nyc i convert time to utc and my friend in japan converts time utc at the same time, it's going to be the same?

Comment: There's no real "converting" that's going on when switching to UTC time. It's the same everywhere and doesn't depend on timezones. In NYC and Japan it's the same time regardless of what the local time is. Time zones are generally listed using positive or negative offsets from UTC.